# Adicionar e Remover porcentagem proporcionalmente

Tags: javascript, matemática

A dúvida é em matemática, um cálculo que será usado em um programa.

Vamos supor que eu tenho 3 itens com porcentagens diferentes:

```
Item 1 - 10%
Item 2 - 40%
Item 3 - 50%
```

Eu quero retirar por exemplo 10% do Item 3 e distribuir essa porcentagem nos outros dois de forma proporcional, gerando o seguinte resultado:

```
Item 1 - 12%
Item 2 - 48%
Item 3 - 40%
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do cálculo ou como faço para chegar nesse resultado?

Comment: Em que linguagem de programação vai fazer isso?

Comment: Irei fazer em javascript

Comment: São sempre 3 itens, e a distribuição é sempre do terceiro para os outros dois?

Comment: Não há ordem @bfavaretto, eu posso remover ou adicionar de qualquer item, e a quantidade adicionada/removida eu tenho que redistribuir proporcionalmente

Answer (score 2):

Teste assim:

```
var items = {
    item1: 10,
    item2: 40,
    item3: 50
};

function distribuir(el, qtd) {

    var somaTotal = 0,
        nrItems = 0;
    for (var este in items) {
        if (items[el] != items[este]) {
            somaTotal += items[este];
            nrItems++;
        }

    }

    for (var este in items) {
        if (items[el] != items[este]) {
            if (somaTotal == 0) items[este] += qtd / nrItems;
            else items[este] += (items[este] || 1) * qtd / somaTotal;
        } else items[este] -= qtd;
    }
    return items;
}
distribuir('item3', 10); // dá Object {item1: 12, item2: 48, item3: 40}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/u3v6b/)

Comment: Olá Sergio, muito obrigado mesmo. Só deu um problema com os inputs: 100, 0, 0. Como eu consigo tratar quando o valor for 0?

Comment: @user4919, com assim? os items têm valor 100, 0 e 0? e retira % de quem?

Comment: Ai retira 10% do Item 1 (100) por exemplo.

Comment: @user4919, tem razão. Corrigí agora a minha resposta.